# Selenium IE change event not fired

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium

I have a select box which has an event listener on it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#edit-era-code-select').change(function() {
      $.ajax({ 
        url: Drupal.settings.basePath+'era/js', 
        type: 'POST',
        data: "era_code_select="+$(this).val(),
        context: document.body, 
        success: function(){
        window.location.reload(true);
      }
    });  
  });
});
```

It will works fine when using it in ie/ff/...
When doing selenium tests using phpunit it I can see the selectbox being changed but it does not trigger the jquery event change. It only happens in IE. Here is the code that does the command:

```
AbstractSeleniumTestCaseIexplore::loginShib ( $user ['uid'] );
  $this->waitForElementPresent("//select[@id='edit-era-code-select']", 30000);
  $code = $this->getSelectedLabel("//select[@id='edit-era-code-select']");
  if ($code != 3333) {
    $this->select("edit-era-code-select", "label=3333");
    $this->waitForPageToLoad("30000");  
  }
  ...
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm having the same problem with a groovy/grails project.  Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

I solved it like this. Its not optimal but it allows you to continue and test other things.

`$this->runScript("$('#edit-era-code-select').change()");`

Comment: I ran across a similar problem and did end up doing something like this. It should be noted that it requires jQuery to be loaded by the web page though.

Comment: @domidc - this isn't working for me in Selenium 2.  Do you know if there's a different workaround? thx

Answer (score 2):

You can get it work without some hacks, like run script that fire change event. 
Selenium generate javascript from your code and inject it in browser, than run it. But if you change selected option of any select via javascript it never work.

I've done small example in order to understand that(if you change selected option by hands 'change' event fire, but via javascript not. You can check workable example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PVX4S/)):

```
<select  id="someTxt">
    <option value="1">Option1</option>
    <option value="2">Option2</option>
    <option value="3">Option3</option>
</select>
<div id="button">Change selected option via javascript</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#someTxt').change(function() {
        alert($("#someTxt option:selected").text());
      });
    $("#button").bind("click", function(){
      $("#someTxt option[value='3']").attr('selected', 'selected');
    });
    });
 </script>
```

**So i think this is okay to fire event manually like:**

```
$this->runScript("$('#edit-era-code-select').change()");
```

Comment: this no longer works in IE for me in Selenium 2.3.  Do you know if there's a different workaround?

Comment: dagger.  Thanks for replying anyway, I'll continue the search.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the focus first:

```
runScript("document.getElementById('selectboxID').focus())
```

This problem will happen in IE browser

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sending keypress events to the select instead of directly modifying the value?