# PhantomJS is clearing out fields after sendKeys had previously populated them

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, bots

I wait for an element to appear then I try to populate it with `SendKeys`. 40% of the time the element isn't populated even though the element is enabled and displayed. I put all kinds of Thread.Sleep with all kinds of values everywhere.

My issue is similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505588/selenium-webdriver-is-clearing-out-fields-after-sendkeys-had-previously-populate) but I'm using the PhantomJS driver instead of the Firefox one. Using the solutions from the link above didn't work, I just got undefined function exceptions.

```
public static IWebElement FindElement(this IWebDriver driver, By by, int timeoutInSeconds)
{
    if (timeoutInSeconds > 0)
    {
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
        return wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(by));
    }
    return driver.FindElement(by);
}    


zipcode = _driver.FindElement(By.Name("iZipCode"), 50);
while(!zipcode.Displayed)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
}
zipcode.Click();
zipcode.Clear();        
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
zipcode.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Backspace);
zipcode.SendKeys(text);
```

The element that I'm trying to populate is a textbox that appears upon a combobox selection. I click element in combobox -> textbox is displayed (it is hidden prior to selection of item in combobox).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using Enter fixed the issued:

```
zipcode.SendKeys(text);
zipcode.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);
```